# Confusing behaviour of mktime() function : increasing tm_hour count by one

Tags: c++, dst, mktime

I am executing below code.

```
int main()
{
struct tm storage={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char *p = NULL; 
p = (char *)strptime("2012-08-25 12:23:12","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
char buff[1024]={0};
strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
cout << buff << endl;
storage.tm_sec += 20;
strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
cout << buff << endl;
mktime(&storage);
strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
cout << buff << endl;
return 0;
}
```

If above Program executed, It prints ' 2012-08-25 13:23:32' instead of '2012-08-25 12:23:32'. Please Help, why it is increasing tm_hour value.
This works correctly if I put input date as '2012-02-25 12:23:32' in program, which is confusing.

OUtput ->

```
[user@rtpkvm55-vm2 root]$ ./a.out
2012-08-25 12:23:12
2012-08-25 12:23:32
2012-08-25 13:23:32
[user@rtpkvm55-vm2 root]$
```

Date Info on my system, -->

```
[user@rtpkvm55-vm2 root]$ date
Sat Aug 25 08:28:26 EDT 2012
```

Comment: The code doesn't show that the hour is increasing. To do that, display the result that came from `strptime` as well as the result that came from the call to `mktime`. That will help pin down what's actually happening.

Comment: Sorry, I can't parse that. It has three outputs instead of one, but no indication of where they came from. Please update the sample code to match the output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**What happens**

The date you specified has daylight savings in effect but when calling `mktime`, `storage.tm_isdst` is zero. `mktime` sees this and thinks "hey, they gave me a date with an incorrect daylight savings flag, lets fix it". Then it sets `tm_isdst` to 1 and changes `tm_hour`.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7541677/79455) answer.

**To fix it**

- use [`timegm`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/timegm.3.html) instead of `mktime`
- set the timezone to UTC before calling `mktime` (see also example from `timegm`) :

  ```
  setenv("TZ", "", 1);
  tzset();
  mktime();
  ```
- use a good date-time library (like [boost::locale::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/dates_times_timezones.html)/[boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/date_time.html), but read the Q&A section on the `boost::locale::date_time` page before picking one)

Comment: Thanks, It Helped and explained me my doubt. Now I need to run my piece of code on both type of system(DST on & off). e.g. If I put tm_isdst = 1 in code before calling to mktime(), it will give incorrect result on system where DST is off(it will end up decreasing tm_hour by one). Is there any other way to add seconds to given date? (It May be "avoid using mktime()" or "Make smart use of mktime() which will ignore tm_isdst flag")

Comment: @DhirajNeve: I added a couple of fixes. If you need to do more date/time related things, I think you should use a good C++ date/time library.

Comment: Isn't `timegm` POSIX only?

Comment: @stackptr `timegm` is a GNU extension and is not in POSIX. I think on Windows you have `_mkgmtime` which does the same thing if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Wow, there just is no way around it. It must be a bug in your system's implementation of mktime(3). mktime(3) should not alter the `struct tm *` passed to it.</strike>

I would suggest checking the value of `storage.tm_isdst`. Try setting it to 0 to ensure it's not confused about DST. If that doesn't work, try setting it to -1 to let it auto determine the proper value.

[mktime - convert broken-down time into time since the Epoch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mktime.html)

> A positive or 0 value for tm_isdst causes mktime() to presume initially that Daylight Savings Time, respectively, is or is not in effect for the specified time. A negative value for tm_isdst causes mktime() to attempt to determine whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect for the specified time.

---

I was wrong about mktime(3) not modifying `struct tm *`. It is the correct behavior to normalize the value.

Comment: According to `man mktime` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) it can (and does) alter `stuct tm`. It normalizes its values and fills in missing fields.

Comment: @rve it looks like you are right. I was misunderstood the wording. I thought it was normalizing for the purpose setting time_t.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `tm_isdst` in the `tm` struct otherwise it is uninitialised, and thus gets set to a random garbage value. Then, when you call `mktime` depending on which random garbage is in `tm_isdst` variable, it either applies daylight saving time or it doesn't, seemingly unpredictably.

However, if you set it to `-1`, you tell `mktime` that you don't know whether daylight saving time is in effect, so the first call to `mktime` will fix it.

Therefore, the simplest way to fix this issue is adding:

```
storage.tm_isdst = -1;
```

before calling `mktime`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to fix your code:

```cpp
int main()
{

    // Need to know if daylight saving is on or off, use the following trick
    // Get the current time in seconds since epoch, convert it to local time,
    // tm_isdst(is daylight saving) value, in the tm variable returned by the localtime(), will be set accordingly
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *tm2= localtime(&now); 
    
    struct tm storage={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,tm2->tm_isdst}; // Note: used the is daylight saving on flag fetched above
    char *p = NULL; 
    p = (char *)strptime("2012-08-25 12:23:12","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
    char buff[1024]={0};
    strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
    cout << buff << endl;
    storage.tm_sec += 20;
    strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
    cout << buff << endl;
    mktime(&storage);
    strftime(buff,1024,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&storage);
    cout << buff << endl;
    return 0;

}
```